# AIX: mptconfig equivalent

Tags: aix, scsi

On hpux i use mptconfig to show speed and other info about scsi controller.
There is something similar on aix?

Comment: use lsdev -C class to locate the device, then lsattr -E -l /dev/foo1 to list attributes about device foo1

Comment: Add to answer,so i can make it as solution found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible to see the max speed with smitty devices and then select scsi

Answer (score 1):

use `lsdev -C class` to locate the device,

- class can be tape, net, hdisk

This will list all device belonging to class, along with (a cryptic) hardware path.

then `lsattr -E -l /dev/foo1` to list attributes about device foo1